# Converting T-SQL to Linq

Tags: linq-to-entities

I am new to LINQ and have been asked to update our existing legacy solution to Linq to Entities in EF4.1.

The EF model is here
http://i53.tinypic.com/2h6sy0m.png

I can manage with the basic queries but the expansive ones, such as below, are causing major headaches. I would appreciate any advice you would have to offer in converting this over to Linq (Return Me.ObjectContext.**** ....)

```
SELECT     tblInspectionFailures.ID, vwBusinessUnit.Name, vwBuilds.BuildNo, tblFaultArea.Description AS [Fault Area], tblFault.Description AS Fault, 
                      tblFaultsCodes.Description AS [Fault Code], tblFaultsCodesDetail.Description AS [Fault Code Detail], 
                      tblFaultCode_AuditScores.Description AS [Audit Score], tblInspectionFailures.Comment, tblInspectionFailures.ShortagePart, 
                      tblInspectionFailures.CreatedDate, vwUsers.DisplayName AS [Created By], tblInspectionFailures.IsAdhocTest, tblInspectionFailures.FixedDate
FROM         tblInspectionFailures INNER JOIN
                      tblFaultArea ON tblFaultArea.ID = tblInspectionFailures.FaultAreaID INNER JOIN
                      vwBuilds ON tblInspectionFailures.BuildID = vwBuilds.ID INNER JOIN
                      tblFaultsCodes ON tblInspectionFailures.FaultCodeID = tblFaultsCodes.ID INNER JOIN
                      vwBusinessUnit ON tblInspectionFailures.BUID = vwBusinessUnit.ID INNER JOIN
                      vwUsers ON tblInspectionFailures.CreatedBy = vwUsers.ID INNER JOIN
                      tblFault ON tblInspectionFailures.FaultID = tblFault.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tblFaultCode_AuditScores ON tblInspectionFailures.AuditScoreID = tblFaultCode_AuditScores.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tblFaultsCodesDetail ON tblInspectionFailures.FaultCodeDetailID = tblFaultsCodesDetail.ID
WHERE     (tblInspectionFailures.FaultAreaID IN (28, 72, 78)) 
            AND (tblInspectionFailures.CreatedDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-04-01 00:00:00', 102) AND GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query is complicates and has a lot of inner joins and outer joins. This answer is not taking this all into consideration. However what's nice about LINQ providers (such as Entity Framework) is  that they can imply the join relationships directly from the model. I write LINQ queries on a daily basis and they can get pretty complicated sometimes, but I hardly ever need to do explicit joining in my LINQ queries. When you have a design database model and Entity Framework model, you can simply 'dot' everything together without using the LINQ `join` operator.

Enough talking. You the following query as starting point. It gets all the failures from the database within the given data range and for the given failt areas. You can extend it to return exactly what you need, but I hope this helps as a starting point.

```
var faultAreas = new[] { 28, 72, 78 };
var minDate = new DateTime(2011, 04, 01);
var maxDate = DateTime.Now;

var failures =    
    from failure in context.InspectionFailures
    where faultAreas.Contains(failure.FaultAreaID)
    where failure.CreatedDate >= minDate
    where failure.CreatedDate <= maxDate
    select failure;
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Steven. As the failures table basically has a list of lookup IDs what is the best practice on returning the description from the integer lookup? I would then load the resulting data into a IQueryable POCO

Comment: Thanks Steven. By extending the number of From clauses and then specifiying what I want in the Select it has worked.